# Printing on lpt port from command prompt

Tags: printing, printer-control-language

I'm printing on an lpt port from the command prompt. Printer is hp2050 (pcl6). I use this command to print on port 1:

> copy con lpt1

then I give it some text to print:

> "Hello there!"

Then I "throw" the page (print it):

> ^Z (ctrl + Z)

But nothing happens. If I try it multiple times, and then print a test page, I see the text printed on the testpage. So only the page-throw doesn't work. However this works on a hp1000-DOS. Can anyone help, what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send a form feed character (ASCII character 12) to eject the page instead of ^Z.
If you add the following it should eject the page:

> `copy ^L lpt1`

To enter the form feed character, type crtl+L or hold down the alt key and type 012.

Comment: Checked it, perfect! Thank you!